# Spring - factory method for Path

Tags: java, spring, factory, factory-method

I am trying to generate a bean that would represent `java.nio.file.Path` using a static method `Paths.get(String path)`. my current Spring setup looks as follows:

```
<bean id="myPath" class="java.nio.file.Paths" factory-method="get">
    <constructor-arg value="c:\\tmp\\" />
</bean>
```

but it comes back with an excpetion `No matching factory method found: factory method 'get'`. Any ideas why that is the case?

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? It works for me in 3.1.2.

Comment: 2.0, but the solution below worked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

java.nio.file.Paths.get expects URI. Besides, this is xml not java don't use \\

Try as

```
file:/C:/tmp/
```

If you have problems with URI syntax visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_url

Comment: I would not make the constraint not to use ``\\`` in XML: Do not use it in Java either, ``/`` is the right way to do this (platform independent)

Comment: that did the trick. What if I transalte that later to unix system - would that still work?