# How to create a Path bean

Tags: java, spring, factory

I need my Spring application context to include a bean that is a (Java 7) [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) object, with a fixed (known) path-name. What XML bean definition should I use?

This kind of bean has some complications:

- `Path` is an interface, and `Path` objects should be created using the [`Paths.get(String...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) static factory method.
- The static factory method also has an overloaded variant, [`Paths.get(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get%28java.net.URI%29).

As the object *is-a* `Path`, the `class` of the bean should be `Path`:

```
 <bean name="myPath" class="java.nio.file.Path"/>
```

I need to indicate the static factory method to use, which would seem to require a `factory-method` attribute. But the factory method belongs to the `java.nio.file.Paths` class rather than the `java.nio.file.Path` class, so I assume the following would not work:

```
 <bean name="myPath" class="java.nio.file.Path"
    factory-method="java.nio.file.Paths.get"/>
```

Lastly, I need to give the arguments for the factory method. How do I do that? Using nested `constructor-arg` (sic) elements? So, something like this?

```
 <bean name="myPath" class="java.nio.file.Path"
    factory-method="java.nio.file.Paths.get">
    <constructor-arg value="/my/path/name"/>
 </bean>
```

But that does not work: Springs throws a `BeanCreationException`, complaining of "No matching factory method found: factory method 'java.nio.file.Paths.get()'."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some experimenting with [pingw33n's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24262449/545127), I found this worked:

```
 <bean id="myPath" class="java.nio.file.Paths" factory-method="get">
    <constructor-arg value="/my/path" />
    <constructor-arg><array /></constructor-arg>
 </bean>
```

Note:

- Give the name of the *factory* class, rather than the *object* class, as the value of the `class` attribute.
- Give an extra empty `array` constructor argument, to force selection of the correct overload of the factory method. This avoids having to go the round-about route of [instead constructing a file URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13680911/545127).

Answer (score 0):

Well , i had the same problem as you , and my solution was ...

```
<bean id="ThreadRunnerConfigFile" class="java.nio.file.Paths" factory-method="get" c:_0="ThreadRunnerConfigFileStr" />
```

Dont forget to include the c namespace on your .xml configuration file

Answer (score -1):

Something like below should help.

```
<bean id="myPath" class="java.nio.file.Paths" factory-method="get">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="/my/path/name" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Nope: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myPath' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'pathFactory'; factory method 'get()'`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod"><value>java.nio.file.Paths.get</value></property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <array>
            <value>/my/path/name</value>
            <array/>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Nope: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myPath' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: No matching factory method found: factory method 'java.nio.file.Paths.get()'`.